# Bootstrap table footer hide and show

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to show and hide the footer of a bootstrap table based on some conditions.

How can I show and hide footer using a `javascript` or `Jquery` event?

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-url="/gh/get/response.json/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/docs/data/data1/" data-show-footer="true">
```

How can I set the value of `data-show-footer="true"` using `Javascript`?

Answer (score 0):

Giving id or class to a table is a must. [Read Me](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/). Then you can do something like this:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("table").getAttribute('data-show-footer')); //true
```

For all table elements you need to use class:

```
var len = document.getElementsByClassName("table");
for (let i=0; i< len.length;i++){
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("table")[i].getAttribute('data-show-footer'));
}
```

Now you are able to access all elements
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6tm1tt3/155/)
Since you now know how to get the value it should be easy for you to construct `if` statement, so if() then `document.getElementsByClassName("table")[i].setAttribute('data-show-footer',false);`

Answer (score 0):

give id to the table e.g `id="tbl"` and in jquery you can do like

```
if(condition)
{
   $("#tbl").attr("data-show-footer", "true");
}
else
{
   $("#tbl").attr("data-show-footer", "false");
}
```

here is the example of implementation http://jsfiddle.net/L6tm1tt3/166/

Comment: I want to hide a footer based on id of the table but above code is not working

Comment: @Rameshbalusamy i have added example of implemenatation